# Setting first char uppercase when setting state in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm making an axios get request, to the PokeApi, and I want to be able to set the first letter uppercase when I retrieve the name,

```
     axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu')
    .then(res =>{
        console.log(res.data)
        console.log(res.data.sprites.front_default)
        this.setState({
            image: res.data.sprites.front_default,
            name: res.data.name
        }, this.upperCaseNameHandler(this.state.name))
    })
}
```

I tried using a handler as such:

```
  upperCaseNameHandler = (pokeName) =>{
    this.setState({
        name: pokeName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pokeName.slice(1)
    })
}
```

I'm not a big fan of using a callback in setState, and I don't feel this is the best practice.

Should I manipulate the data directly, or should I use some sort of handler to then change the state? 
Otherwise is it not a good practice to pass the state in as an argument? However, I'm a bit in doubt of what the alternative is? since there is no locale variable reference in scope when I call the handler.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but why not just `this.setState({name: res.data.name[0].toUpperCase() + res.data.name.slice(1)})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just set the name to upper case in the first `setState` call. Not only does this make the code easier to read, but it will also avoid another render.

```
 axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu')
.then(res =>{
    console.log(res.data)
    console.log(res.data.sprites.front_default)
    this.setState({
        image: res.data.sprites.front_default,
        name: res.data.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + res.data.name.slice(1)
    })
})
```

Comment: Easiest solution

Comment: @baileyhaldwin cool, if you think this is the best answer can you select it as the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left so others can find the answer easier?

Comment: Of course! Feel free to upvote my answer as well if you think it deserves it :)

Comment: @baileyhaldwin haha of course, glad I could help :)